# How to index range values in Lucene?

Tags: lucene

I am constructing documents in Lucene that have mutiple fields with range values like :
(item, price) :
(A,    2 - 5),
(A,    10 - 12),
(B,    15 - 20),
(B,    80 - 91)

I can differentiate items and item values based on name. Such as for item A, my lucene field name would be "itemA", and for B, "itemB". How can I index different ranges in lucene?